# Class App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, exception, controller, routes

I'm new in Laravel and I can't understand why the controller doesn't work. Can you help me? Thanks.

This is the `routes.php` file:

[routes.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEyRK.jpg)

This is the `WelcomeController` controller:

[WelcomeController.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9qa9.jpg)

and this is the exception trowed:

> ReflectionException in Container.php line 737:
>
> Class App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController does not exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `WelcomeController.php` file in directory `Controllers`, and you have it in `Controllers/Auth`

I'd suggest to:

```
$>php artisan make:controller WelcomeController
```

Comment: Firstly sorry for my misspellings, my english is not perfect.
And secondly thank you very much for the fast and correctly answer.

Comment: `Method App\Http\Controllers\HomeController::index() does not exist` this is my error. What may go wrong?

Comment: @partho That you need to create the method?

Comment: you should use this one php artisan make:controller WelcomeController not this one  WelcomeController.php.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using the laravel 8 then you can use the below-mentioned code in your web.php route file

```
use App\Http\Controllers\WelcomeController;

Route::get('/', [WelcomeController::class, 'index'])->name('welcome');
```

For more information use the laravel 8 documentation https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing

Answer (score 0):

if you forget to choose your method:

```
 Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController')->name('welcome');
```

change it to:

```
 Route::get('/', [WelcomeController::class, 'index'])->name('welcome');
```

or

```
 Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@YOUR_METHOD_NAME')->name('welcome');
```